# XAML linking failures when i run application

Tags: c#, xaml

When i run my C#/XAML app, i have several display failures in the application banner. I don't understand what these errors are.

[Screen shot of debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOGak.png)

[Application banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8RO9.png)

ListBox data is a List<object

My listbox code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="LB_Group" Style="{StaticResource ListBox}" Margin="0,0,0,0" SelectionChanged="LB_Group_SelectionChanged" FontSize="14">
                <ListBox.Resources>
                    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.Resources>
            </ListBox>
```

The style :

```
<Style x:Key="ListBox" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                <Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" 
                                    BorderThickness="1"/>
                    <ScrollViewer Focusable="false" IsTabStop="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="true"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Border.Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Hi Sylvain, welcome to StackOverFlow. To be able to help you, we need more information and some code. You can take a look at this link to understand how to detail your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.